# Not able to exit the while loop after the click is not available

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

What I am trying to achieve is that I have a list of similar elements present in a page from which I want to extract the attribute from the element. While doing so once one page is done the code should click the next button until till the last page and perform the similar operation of extraction once done move to the next link in the for loop can anyone help me in achieving this, following is the code that I am using what it does is it clicks the next button but never exits the while loop.

```
for link in content[currentIndex:]:
    now = datetime.now()
    # dd/mm/YY H:M:S
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    print("date and time =", dt_string)
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        while driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-last').click():
            try:
                while driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-disabled a-last.a-last'):
                    print("nothing here")
                    break
            except NoSuchElementException:
                aa = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
                    '.sg-col-4-of-24.sg-col-4-of-12.sg-col-4-of-36.s-result-item.sg-col-4-of-28.sg-col-4-of-16.sg-col.sg-col-4-of-20.sg-col-4-of-32')
                for j in aa:
                    hd = j.get_attribute('data-asin')
                    hd1 = "'" + hd
                    print(hd1)
                    f.write(link + "," + hd1 + "\n")
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-last').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

The link that I am using is "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_in_h_p_89_87?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=i%3Atoys-and-games-intl-ship%2Cn%3A%2116225015011%2Cn%3A276729011%2Cp_89%3AHobby+Products+International&bbn=16225015011&ie=UTF8&qid=1578465210&rnid=2528832011" in this i want to extract attribute "data-asin" for all the elements.

can any one help seriously i am stuck at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `data-asin` value from all elements and from all pages for a given [link](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_in_h_p_89_87?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=i%3Atoys-and-games-intl-ship%2Cn%3A%2116225015011%2Cn%3A276729011%2Cp_89%3AHobby%20Products%20International&bbn=16225015011&ie=UTF8&qid=1578465210&rnid=2528832011)

Use infinite while loop and check for length of the button.if not exit.

To get all the `data-asin` values induce `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following css selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_in_h_p_89_87?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=i%3Atoys-and-games-intl-ship%2Cn%3A%2116225015011%2Cn%3A276729011%2Cp_89%3AHobby+Products+International&bbn=16225015011&ie=UTF8&qid=1578465210&rnid=2528832011")
dataAsin = []
while True:

    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row >div[data-asin]")))
    for element in elements:
        dataAsin.append(element.get_attribute("data-asin"))

    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.a-disabled.a-last")) > 0:
        break;
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.a-last >a")) > 0:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.a-last >a").click()
    else:
        break;

print(dataAsin)
print(len(dataAsin))
```

**Output**:

```
['B018EMT6SC', 'B076SYTFBD', 'B0044TPTTU', 'B002KCU5NI', 'B078HD9T7Q', 'B01HBX9OXW', 'B002KCQHJE', 'B0734D66VZ', 'B006ON7DB6', 'B0163MYTDM', 'B000LZPJQO', 'B00XI6BVU6', 'B00KDKJ3GO', 'B00XI6CC9K', 'B001S79QXQ', 'B002KD02KI', 'B016QR5YP6', 'B00XI7I5AE', 'B00YASDU4Q', 'B00S9YG31E', 'B0017KI18K', 'B07FQTGYZJ', 'B00G7NZ41E', 'B001FECAO4', 'B000BLM2WM', 'B001FQF6NE', 'B07NZ8DGHJ', 'B0734F3YGR', 'B01N3A5XK0', 'B00LUEGNJC', 'B00G7NZHO8', 'B00G7NZHJ8', 'B00G7NZHFC', 'B00G7NZGFI', 'B00G7NZ5CM', 'B00CIENEA4', 'B00B8NS17W', 'B00B8NNG40', 'B00B8NNAIC', 'B009OY7VQE', 'B00731MJ8U', 'B00731KXII', 'B006YBD30S', 'B006P196I0', 'B0057CM7XY', 'B004NF7IV2', 'B004NF29OI', 'B004G8ULMY', 'B00423K95C', 'B0038VXJSI', 'B0037Y922S', 'B002UNDO76', 'B001L2G79E', 'B001FQGMDC', 'B001BHI88C', 'B0017KHCF8', 'B000WTD4JS', 'B07BHDFNF5', 'B07BHD1GWC', 'B0734FPYDK', 'B0734DD7VG', 'B0734D65HG', 'B0734D5D55', 'B0734CCTGY', 'B0734CCQ2H', 'B0734C1JW6', 'B0734BP4PZ', 'B0734BFLX1', 'B0734B724T', 'B07349ZPJQ', 'B073496PC4', 'B073492BX5', 'B073489R7T', 'B07347C8CY', 'B01N4U9OGM', 'B01MTFAV1H', 'B0163MZ7UG', 'B0163MYQJO', 'B0163MYPWM', 'B00G7NZLU8', 'B00G7NZI4C', 'B00G7NZH9S', 'B00G7NZFPO', 'B00G7NZEWS', 'B00G7NZEFK', 'B00G7NZE78', 'B00G7NZ914', 'B00G7NZ3GU', 'B00G7NZ2ES', 'B00BCU7EDI', 'B00731MLT2', 'B00731MBOW', 'B006ZZAZ0Y', 'B006ZZAYUK', 'B0057CM9K0', 'B0057CM01S', 'B0038VSHGC', 'B002KCQJ5G', 'B00261J7WS', 'B001S77QME', 'B001HSBXDC', 'B001FQMG8M', 'B001CBEWDC', 'B001BG4SLO', 'B000UZEOKC', 'B000LZSFH4', 'B000LZNVDM', 'B000FTOKN4', 'B000BN2XQK', 'B000BLGA1G']
110
```

Comment: Thanks @KunduK it does what is expected saved me big time  but however it does not scraped if there is no next button can you tweak the above code to scrape if there is no next button

Comment: @sachinsafale : That is what I did.did you run the entire code the link you have shared on your post?

Comment: yes absolutely i did but it runs perfectly fine for the ones having next button but not for the ones that dont have next button

Comment: can you share such link here?

Comment: "https://www.amazon.com/s?i=toys-and-games-intl-ship&bbn=16225015011&rh=n%3A%2116225015011%2Cn%3A196601011%2Cp_lbr_characters_browse-bin%3AFrozen&dc&fst=as%3Aoff&qid=1578463918&rnid=3296952011&ref=sr_in_-2_p_lbr_characters_bro_62" this is one of those

Comment: @sachinsafale : Check my updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

I think put click() action as statement of while loop is not a good method.

I recommend to use Explicit Waits instead of try-except.

Try to remove all try-except and while loop, modify your code as below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  //Explicit Waits to wait for ExpectedCondition

aa = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.sg-col-4-of-24.sg-col-4-of-12.sg-col-4-of-36.s-result-item.sg-col-4-of-28.sg-col-4-of-16.sg-col.sg-col-4-of-20.sg-col-4-of-32')))
for j in aa:
    hd = j.get_attribute('data-asin')
    hd1 = "'" + hd
    print(hd1)
    f.write(link + "," + hd1 + "\n")

next_btn = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.a-last')))
if 'disabled' not in next_btn.get_attribute("class"):
    next_btn.click()
```

Reference of Explicit Waits:
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-last').click():
```

change it to

```
 driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a-disabled a-last').click():
```

hope this helps

Comment: After changing that it does not move to the next page rather gets the elements from the first page and exits

Comment: change loop condition to this  <while True:>  and check.

Comment: doesnt seem to help that either